# SQL execution difference in Postgres/Redshift/SparkSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am not sure if I should post this question in this forum. I search in google but didn't got any good answers.  I was asked below question during one of my interviews and  was not able to answer .Does anyone have the answer ?

Consider the query `SELECT * FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.x = bar.x WHERE foo.primary_key = ?`. What happens if you run this in Postgres? How does that differ if you run it in Redshift, or SparkSQL

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?  Do you mean that question mark as a literal `?`, or is it a placeholder in your question?

Comment: I am not sure @JeffUK.that `?` is just a question mark

Comment: It makes a big difference,  `?` is an operator in SQL.

Comment: @JeffUK . . . It is not an operator in standard SQL.  What are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe operator is the wrong word; I was referring to their use as placeholders in prepared statements, I was trying to determine if they meant `=?` or `=Some Value`